# symfony, sonta user bundle, many to many

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata-user-bundle

I'm doing a little project, in which I use sonata user bundle to administrate easily my users.

But I have another entity who is named order. In this entity is linked with one user. 
Where have I to write the manyToOne anotation?

Thanks
Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using sonata admin then you can easily extend its core bundles using [`EASYEXTENDS BUNDLE`](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/easy-extends/master/doc/index.html) it will generate a child bundle e.g

> php app/console sonata:easy-extends:generate SonataUserBundle -d src [`Reference`](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/user/2-2/doc/reference/installation.html)

Once you have extended bundle for `SonataUserBundle` you can specify your relations in child bundle's entity or its doctrine config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping
                  http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
    <entity name="Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User" table="fos_user_user">
        <id name="id" column="id" type="integer">
            <generator strategy="AUTO" />
        </id>
        <one-to-many  field="orders" target-entity="Order" mapped-by="user" />
    </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

In your user entity

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\BaseUser as BaseUser;
class User extends BaseUser
{
    protected $orders;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->orders= new ArrayCollection();
    }
//.. Getter and setter
}
```

In your order entity add mapping to point back to user entity

```
class Order
{
    protected $user;
}
```

In order doctrine config file define mapping to user entity

```
<many-to-one  field="user" target-entity="User" inversed-y="orders" join-column="user_id">
```

If you are using annotations you can find equivalent mapping from [`Docs`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#relationship-mapping-metadata)

Comment: Thanks a lot, with this informations, I can not only do that, but understand a lot of other things of my sonata user bundle!!